# how to bind product price on product variation in ionic 3 and woocommerce

Tags: angularjs, woocommerce, ionic3

My list.html file this file contains the list of products I am fetching using Woocommerce API.Its all working good but I am not able to bind the variation price with each variation.Because in woocommerce each variation has its own id and price is given in that array.I am so confused how to get the price on its particular variation.

```
<ion-slide>  <!--This slide is for fruits-->
  <ion-card *ngFor="let product of products" no-padding>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-thumbnail item-start>
        <img-loader *ngIf="product.images" src="{{product.images[1].src}}" 
          useImg>
        </img-loader>
      </ion-thumbnail>
      <h4 top text-wrap>{{product.name}}</h4>
      <p>Rs.{{product.price*product.quantity}}</p>
      <ion-icon icon-only class="dec" name="remove-circle" 
          (click)="decrement(product)">
      </ion-icon>
      {{product.quantity}}
      <ion-icon icon-only class="inc" name="add-circle" 
        (click)="increment(product)">
      </ion-icon>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item *ngFor="let attr of product.attributes">
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="qty" placeholder="QTY">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let opt of attr.options" [value]="opt">
           {{ opt }}
        </ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>       
    <button color="light" class="addbtn" ion-button clear >add</button>

   </ion-card>
  </ion-slide>
```

this is my list.ts file I am using getAynsc() to get the data.

```
   this.WooCommerce.getAsync('products?
    category=34&per_page=10').then((result) => {

  console.log(JSON.parse(result.toJSON().body));
  this.products = JSON.parse(result.toJSON().body);
  console.log(this.products);
  this.productsvv.forEach(product => { product.quantity = 1; });
  this.products.forEach(product => { product.quantity = 1; });
  return JSON.parse(result.toJSON().body);



}, (err) => {
  console.log(err)


})
```

Comment: please don't paste image reference for code. post em here it's easy for us to go through that and the post as well. Also it's not a good practise to post the code in image format

Comment: Ok I will remember that..

Comment: Please help ASAP